# Instantiating a type parameter without a no-arg constructor

Tags: scala

I have a class hierarchy of `Item`s that each need a corresponding `ItemTemplate` instance as a constructor parameter. I'd like to write a generic function to instantiate any `Item` subclass by giving it `Item` and `ItemTemplate` as type parameters, using it like this:

```
val newItem = instantiateItem[ItemClass, TemplateClass](templateInstance)
```

After a bit of research I now have

```
def instantiateItem[I, T](implicit mf: Manifest[I], template: T): I = {
    val constructor = mf.erasure.getConstructor(classOf[T])
    constructor.newInstance(template).asInstanceOf[I]
}
```

But this doesn't compile, the `classOf[T]` gives the error

> Class type required but T found

I tried replacing `classOf[T]` with `classManifest[CM].erasure` but this doesn't work as CM needs to be context bounded to `ClassManifest`, and apparently it's not possible to use bounded type parameters with implicit parameters.

Is it possible to do what I want here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the `template` class simply by calling `template.getClass`. It requires `template` to be a subtype of `AnyRef`, so either you cast it to `AnyRef` (forcing boxing of primitive types) or you add an upper bound for `T`:

```
def instantiateItem[I, T <: AnyRef](implicit mf: Manifest[I], template: T): I = {
  val constructor = mf.erasure.getConstructor(template.getClass)
  constructor.newInstance(template).asInstanceOf[I]
}
```

If you want to pass in `template` explicitly, as indicated by the code in your question, you need to separate implicit and explicit arguments, e.g.

```
def instantiateItem[I, T <: AnyRef](template: T)(implicit mf: Manifest[I]): I = {
  val constructor = mf.erasure.getConstructor(template.getClass)
  constructor.newInstance(template).asInstanceOf[I]
}
```

aka

```
def instantiateItem[I : Manifest, T <: AnyRef](template: T): I = {
  val mf = implicitly[Manifest[I]]
  val constructor = mf.erasure.getConstructor(template.getClass)
  constructor.newInstance(template).asInstanceOf[I]
}
```

---

In general if possible you could avoid having to use reflection at all with careful design:

```
trait ItemCompanion[I,T] {
   def instantiateItem(template: T): I
}

object TestItem extends ItemCompanion[TestItem, TestTemplate] {
   implicit def self: ItemCompanion[TestItem, TestTemplate] = this
   def instantiateItem(template: TestTemplate): TestItem = new TestItem(template)
}
class TestItem(template: TestTemplate)
trait TestTemplate

// try out
def instantiateItem[I, T](implicit ic: ItemCompanion[I, T], t: T): I =
   ic.instantiateItem(t)

implicit val temp: TestTemplate = new TestTemplate {}
instantiateItem[TestItem, TestTemplate]
```

Comment: This compiles, but I have a problem calling it:
not enough arguments for method instantiateItem: (implicit mf: Manifest[I], implicit template: T)I. Unspecified value parameter template.

Comment: How does your call look? It ought to be `instantiateItem[TestItem, TestTemplate]`

Comment: In your question you pass the `template` parameter explicitly. Then you will have to pass in _both_ parameters (first the manifest, then the template). If you want _that_, you should define the method with two argument lists, e.g. `def instantiateItem[I, T <: AnyRef](template: T)(implicit mf: Manifest[I]): I`

Answer (score 1):

These corrections to your code should do the trick:

```
def instantiateItem[I : Manifest, T <: AnyRef : Manifest](template: T): I = {
    val constructor = manifest[I].erasure.getConstructor(manifest[T].erasure)
    constructor.newInstance(template).asInstanceOf[I]
}
```

The `I : Manifest` syntax is a preferred sugarred version of your implicit parameter.

Please note that since Scala 2.10 `Manifest` will be deprecated in favor of `TypeTag`

Comment: @hezamu Right. The `T` had to be restricted to be of `AnyRef` subtype. Please see the update - it compiles.

Comment: Yes, now it compiles. I'm still a bit unclear how I should call it, the way I described in the question does not apply here.

Comment: @hezamu What you've described in the question is perfectly applicable here, but it is a bit superfluous since, the `T` type can be resolved from the `template` parameter, so there's no need to specify that. In other words, you can use it like so: `instantiateItem[ItemClass](templateInstance)`